# checked checkbox value shown in input textbox and uncheck will another place

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

i have  two page one page home page another page defaults results . i have check box in home page . its code looks like

```
 <div class="col-md-1 padding-lft" style="right:13px;top:3px">
      <input id="chkUFtoLoan-1" name="S"  value="S" type="checkbox" checked /> 
 </div>
```

i have  passed this value another page looks like

```
<?php 
     $checkbox1 = $_POST["S"];
     echo $checkbox1 = $_POST["S"];
?>
```

Now i have results two section BUYER CLOSE TO SECTION and ABOUT YOUR LOAN.
 in results page i have value **UPFRONT MIP VALUE**

**ABOUT YOUR LOAN**

```
  <div class="row content green">
      <label id="Label3" for="purchasePrice" class="pull-left ">Upfront MIP Financed</label>


  <label id="financedmip-Buyer"  class="pull-right">$<?php echo round($arrFirstBox["upfrontmipamt"],2);?>
```

**BUYER CLOSE TO SECTION**

```
 <label id="Label3" for="purchasePrice" class="pull-left ">Upfront MIP Financed</label>
 <label id="financedmip-Buyer"  class="pull-right">$<?php echo round($arrFirstBox["upfrontmipamt"],2);?>
```

Both value same if user checked check box home page value goes to about your loan or user  checkbox unchecked values BUYER CLOSE TO SECTION.
i have written script code

```
$('input[Name="S"]').mouseenter(function() { 
    var text = "";
    $('#financedmip:checked').each(function(){
        text += $(this).val('<?php echo round($arrFirstBox["upfrontmipamt"],2);?>')+',';
    });
    text = text.substring(0,text.length-1);

    $('#financedmip-Buyer').val(0);
});
```

MY script  i did mistake please any one find what mistake  did?  please any one find my mistake ?

Comment: what for you use PHP ?

Comment: my file extension php@PaulBooblic

Comment: Brother . if  user select checkbox in home page UPFRONT MIP value display to ABOUT YOUR LOAN if user un check value display TO BUYER CLOSE TO SECTION@Amitsingh

Comment: provide full code or fiddle

Comment: @PaulBooblic please see my link  https://jsfiddle.net/v1L7ncxw/

Comment: your code is not working, please totally describe your task? why you using php? you have no form to post your data to php, may be you can do it on client-side?

Comment: I am using two php File . first file name  calculate .php and  defaults_results.php. IN my calculate  have check box. if user select check  box check value goes to display next page mean defaults_results.php  in About your loan section . if user un check value goes to display next page Buyer close to section in next page its my task

Comment: try this example http://jsfiddle.net/of4h29kp/ , if you need to get some data from php you should use ajax

Comment: thank you @paul Booblic i will check

Answer (score 1):

Use

> isset($_POST["S"])

in your php script and validate it. If the value is set/checked you can navigate to 'ABOUT YOUR LOAN' section else to the other section.

```
if(isset($_POST["S"])){
//ABOUT YOUR LOAN
} else {
// TO BUYER CLOSE TO SECTION
}
```

Comment: i have pass my script id if condition ?

Comment: Hope this helped you. You can upvote only if it fits your need.

Comment: ok i did  bro. i need  i have pass my label id  in this script?

Comment: Can you please explain your doubt clearly. I am missing it.

Comment: i have  two  section value display  if user select check box value display  About your Loan  if un check value goes to Buyer close to section please see my  link https://jsfiddle.net/v1L7ncxw/